# Android capture hardware keyboard event without edittext view

Tags: android, keyboard, hardware-interface

How can I capture the hardware keyboard events without using an EditText field?

For example, in a simple activity the display a square on the screen, when a "B" is pressed on the slide keyboard I want to turn it blue, when a "G" is presses, turn it Green, etc.

I don't need help with the color code, just how to intercept the keypress

This is not about the soft or virtual keyboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android classes usually provide event handlers, you can implement when subclassing them. The `Activity` class has the following event handlers:

- `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
- `onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

In addition all views have the following event handlers:

- `onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent)`
- `onKeyUp(int, KeyEvent)`

I guess there are many other classes that have similar event handlers for key events, but this should be enough for your situation. The [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) then contains information about the pressed key, i.e. the key code.

Answer (score 1):

Activity class has already implemented KeyEvent.CallBack see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

you just need to override these methods and implements all events that you want