# Launch my App Activity on Home key pressed

Tags: android, android-tv, android-homebutton

I am developing a Launcher app for Android TV and want to override the functionality of Home button. I want to bring my Application's Activity to top when Home button is pressed so that it acts as default launcher. I tried this [Android Studio TV remote buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479499/android-studio-tv-remote-buttons) but did not work. It is definitely possible because there are button mapper apps on the PlayStore. I have this in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_TV_LISTINGS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name=".AppName"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:banner="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".AppActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER_APP" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".broadcast_receivers.PackageChangeReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

any leads are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some logs?

Comment: I don't have any code to recognize home button pressed action. So I don't have longs.

Comment: IMHO, I think you should add a receiver to interpret home button press action just to test if it works or not.